# Using html in jquery expand collapse

Tags: jquery

I am using expand collapse on my site using jquery and html code bellow:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fulltext').hide();

    $('.blog-item .readmore').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.fulltext').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Close Deals' ? 'More Deals' : 'Close Deals');
    });
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="blog-item">
        <p class='fulltext'>Read more text will be here.</p>
    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more..</a>
</div>
```

Actually I want to use table inside hidden text which is now: `<p class='fulltext'>Read more text will be here.</p>`

But when I use table inside fulltext its stop working. Please any suggestion.

Comment: You should use `prev()` instead of `parent().find('.fulltext');`

Answer (score 1):

Change `<p class="fulltext">` to `<div class="fulltext">` and it should work just fine. You can't have other block elements within a `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` element is designed to describe a container of data whereas `<p>` element is designed to describe a paragraph of content. To use a table inside use `div` tag.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R33hv/)